# Extract data from a specific page using Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python and BeautifulSoup. I wrote the code below to try to call up the website (https://www.fangraphs.com/depthcharts.aspx?position=Team), **scrape** the data in the table and export it to a csv file. I was able to write code to extract data from other tables on the website, but not this particular one. It keeps coming back with: AttributeError: NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Do I have the wrong "class" name? Again, I've very new and trying to teach myself. I have been learning via trial and error and reverse engineering other's codes. This one has me stumped. Any guidance?

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# static urls
season = datetime.datetime.now().year
URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/depthcharts.aspx?position=Team".format(season=season)

# request the data
batting_html = requests.get(URL).text

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(input_html, out_file_name):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a CSV file.
    """
    # parse input
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "tablesoreder, depth_chart tablesorter tablesorter-default"})

    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)
    print(headers)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)

    # write to CSV file
    with open(out_file_name, "w") as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)

parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(batting_html, 'Team War Totals.csv')
```

Comment: Please include your traceback so we don't have to replicate your project to see it.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to edit my original question...Traceback below for now...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " ", line 43, in <module>
    parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(batting_html, 'Team War Totals.csv')
  File " ", line 22, in parse_array_from_fangraphs_html
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Your issue is with `table = soup.find("table", {"class": "tablesoreder, depth_chart tablesorter tablesorter-default"})` (it doesn't find anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback looks like

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ee944e08f675> in <module>()
     41         writer.writerows(rows)
     42 
---> 43 parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(batting_html, 'Team War Totals.csv')

<ipython-input-4-ee944e08f675> in parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(input_html, out_file_name)
     20 
     21     # get headers
---> 22     headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
     23     headers = []
     24     for header in headers_html:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

So yes, the problem is in the

```
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "tablesoreder, depth_chart tablesorter tablesorter-default"})
```

Instruction.

You could modify it in order to split the class attribute upon the spaces, as suggested by another user. But then you would be getting another failure because the parsed table has no tbody.

The fixed script would look like

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# static urls
season = datetime.datetime.now().year
URL = "https://www.fangraphs.com/depthcharts.aspx?position=Team".format(season=season)

# request the data
batting_html = requests.get(URL).text

def parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(input_html, out_file_name):
    """
    Take a HTML stats page from fangraphs and parse it out to a CSV file.
    """
    # parse input
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", class_=["tablesoreder,", "depth_chart", "tablesorter", "tablesorter-default"])

    # get headers
    headers_html = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    headers = []
    for header in headers_html:
        headers.append(header.text)
    print(headers)

    # get rows
    rows = []
    rows_html = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows_html:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):
            row_data.append(cell.text)
        rows.append(row_data)

    # write to CSV file
    with open(out_file_name, "w") as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)

parse_array_from_fangraphs_html(batting_html, 'Team War Totals.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table statement with:

```
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": ["tablesoreder,", "depth_chart", "tablesorter", "tablesorter-default"]})
```

Also once you fix that, your header will not work as the table has a thead which has a tr inside and then finally td. So you have to replace that statement with:

```
headers_html = table.find("thead").find("tr").find_all("th")
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, but it looks like my rows are stuck too ... line 29, in parse_array_from_fangraphs_html
    rows_html = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'